# Visual Studio Deployment: Changing the dll version

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2013

I am developing an single page web application that uses the Oracle.DataAccess dll. When I run the application locally I have to use the 32-bit version for IIS express. When I publish my application, IIS requires that I use the 64-bit version.

I was wondering if there was a way to change which version was included in the references depending if I run it locally vs. publishing it without having to  manually change the dll each time before building.

I am currently developing in Visual Studio 2013 Update 3.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a separate build configuration when deploying vs running locally? If so, you can use the `Condition` attribute of a `Reference` to conditionally evaluate it based on the current build configuration like so:

```
<Reference Include="32 bit Oracle.DataAccess" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'LocalBuild'" />
<Reference Include="64 bit Oracle.DataAccess" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'MyDeploymentBuild'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install both x64 and x86 Oracle version on one machine, see here: [Install both x86 (32-bit) and x64 Oracle Clients on your machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100). Then you can compile your application in either ways without any changes. Just copy the correct version of `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` to your target system.